# Claws Mail default from account setting has changed?

Tags: email, configuration, client

I use claws mail and my system upgraded to the latest **3.14.1**. In the previous version, if I was **looking at email in my personal email account** and clicked Compose, I would get a compose window with the From being my **personal account**. If I was **in my work account**, I would get a compose window with my From being my **work account**.

In the new version, it always defaults to the **"Default Account"** no matter which emails I am looking at. If I reply to an email, it works correctly.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting, which can be configured per folder, or hierarchy of folders, where you can set the default account to use when composing an email when that folder set is selected.

Right click on the folder, and choose properties. After choosing the compose tab on the left, about half way down on the right is a "Default Account" check box. When selected you can choose which account you want to compose with. If you select "Apply to subfolders" on the right of the option, you can set it for all the folders beneath this one too.

**So, if you're on the root account folder, you can set the default compose account for all the folders within an email account.**